# How to rewrite this sql code in HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

[image: my query]

I need to fetch "name" column of the "Manager" table.and show all " Family" columns with "Manager.name" as given above.

```
SELECT Family.id, Family.name,Family.surname, Manager.name[Manager Name]
FROM Family
INNER JOIN Manager
ON Family.managerId=Manager.id;
```

I can execute this SQL query in Managment studio but when I try to add to hibernate ( DAO ) class I had this error :

> Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:
>   ON near line 4, column 1 [SELECT Family.id,
>   Family.name,Family.surname, Manager.name AS ManagerName

Comment: What do you mean by how to use?

Comment: i can execute this sql query in Managment studio but when i try to add to hibernate ( DAO ) class 
i had this error :
 Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ON near line 4, column 1 [SELECT Family.id, Family.name,Family.surname, Manager.name AS ManagerName @Alex

Comment: Please do not post extra information in comments. This is not a forum. Edit your question and add additional information (that you have posted in the comment above).

Comment: sorry.im new here.it was my first question.thanks you for your suggestion

Comment: It is all good. Read this when asking questions on SO or any other site: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: About your problem: I cannot see anything wrong with your SQL except that you need a space `Manager.name [Manager Name]` (just before [). Looking at your err I can see that you have changed that. Please post full SQL query that is actually generating the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to use `ON Family.managerId=Manager.id;`. Just define the relation between the two entities using for exemple :

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="managerId")
private Manager manager;

SELECT f.id, f.name,f.surname, m.name
FROM Family AS f
INNER JOIN Manager AS m
```

> UPDATE

You can load the properties of manager directly, without using INNER JOIN if  Family has a many-to-one relationship to Manager like this :

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="managerId")
private Manager manager;

SELECT f.id, f.name,f.surname, f.manager.name
FROM Family AS f
```

Comment: still i have error.by the way i update my query image